# Why are icons not loading anymore after routing with react router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a page with a grid that displays products. After I route to the product details page, the icons on the top bar are not loading anymore. Why is this happening?

This is my layout component:

```
export default class Layout extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return <div>
            <LoadingScreen/>
            <AppBar/>
            <MyRouter/>
            <Footer/>
            </div>
    }
}
```

my router:

```
const MyRouter = () => {
  return(
    <div
      style={style}
    >
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          component={ProductList}
        />
        <Route
          path="/products/:id"
          exact
          component={ProductPage}
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyRouter
```

and this is how my AppBar looks like:

```
export default class AppBar extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div style={divStyle}>
            <div style={{display:"flex"}}>
                <img
                  alt="logo"
                  style={imgStyle}
                  src="adidasLogo.jpg"/>
                <div style={barButtonsDivStyle}>
                    <BarButton
                      onClick={() => store.dispatch(selectCategory("Men"))}
                      value="Men"/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <BarButton
                      onClick={() => store.dispatch(selectCategory("Women"))}
                      value="Women"/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <BarButton
                      onClick={() => store.dispatch(selectCategory("Kids"))}
                      value="Kids"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style={selectDivStyle}>
                <CurrencySelect
                  options={["USD", "EUR", "MDL"]}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

as you can see the app bar is not even inside the router, why would the icons disappear?

This is what it looks like after I go to the product detail page:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The src attributes are relative paths - the browser URL is changing and so is the root the browser is looking for those pictures in. You'll have to make them absolute URLs, or bundle them if they're static assets.